# replacing text within quotes until next quote

Tags: c#, regex, replace, match

```
String input = "helloj\"iojgeio\r\ngsk\\"jopri\"gj\r\negjoijisgoe\"joijsofeij\"\"\"ojgsoij\"";
```

This is my current code that works but iv added some code that has to run before this which makes
some '"' split onto another line thus making the code below obsolute unless under certain cirumstances 
the '"' is not put onto the next line.

```
firstQuote = input.IndexOf("\"");
lastQuote = input.LastIndexOf("\"");
input = input.Substring(0, firstQuote) + "<span>quote" +
    input.Substring(firstQuote + 1, lastQuote - (firstQuote + 1) + "quote</span>" +
    input.Substring(lastQuote + 1, lines.Length - (lastQuote + 1);
```

How could I change the input string from

```
input = "helloj\"iojgeio\r\ngsk\\"jopri\"gj\r\negjoijisgoe\"joijsofeij\"\"\"ojgsoij\"";
```

to

```
input = "helloj(<span>quoteiojgeio\r\ngsk\\"jopriquote</span>gj\r\negjoijisgoe<span>quotejoijsofeijquote</span><span>quotequote</span>ojgsoijquote";
```

Comment: your example input and output are inconsistent..y that `(` before `span`...y span tag at the end when the quotes are not balanced

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ edited for consistency

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
 @"(?<!\\)\\\""(.*?)(?<!\\)\\\"""
```

and replace it with

```
 <span>quote$1quote</span>
```

Comment: @JordanTrainor that is because \\ is causing it to escape `)`

Comment: I already tested it with a @ before your edit and that just causes everything after the regex error.

Comment: If I use the edited regex on "This is a \"" 1 + "\" number" I get the following output "This is a <span>"" 1 + ""</span> number";